Вопрос по функции client.get_channel(.......)
Имеется бот для Discord, в прошлом работал стабильно, ошибок не выдавал. Пару месяцев не работал с ним, и вот недавно попытался запустить.
Бот запускается до момента идентификации текстового канала для работы в Discord-сообществе.
Запись
channel = client.get_channel(.......)
возвращает значение "None". ID канала корректный, он не менялся и я перепроверил. Не работает и с моего компьютера, и сайта-хостинга python-приложений.
Не было ли за последние месяцы каких-то изменений в библиотеке Discord для python?
p.s. Когда изучал документацию про библиотеку, то про там есть приписка
"Changed in version 2.0: id parameter is now positional-only."- может в этом дело? Я так и не понял, что сие значит.

То что он позиционный я понял. Только от этого не проще.

Кстати, и как это помогает решить мою проблему?

Спасибо, прочитал. Понял, что на мой вопрос это никак не отвечает. Аргумент стоит на верной позиции (кстати, он там один, так что эти сведения вообще не имеют смысла, он обьявлен правильно)

Кстати, полезная инфомрация. Про эти кварги и арги в базовых курсах не обьясняется, хотя это никому не мешает ставить их в скобки во всяких туторах

Во-первых, проверьте точно ли:

Бот находится на том сервере, на котором необходимо найти канал;
Указан верный ID канала;
Указанный ID является типом int;
Указанный канал доступен для бота и он его видит.

Во-вторых, проверьте установлены ли у Вас последние версии python и discord.py.
Проблема может быть в этом.

Да, сам бот по токену полностью загружается. ID канала - число int. Канал доступен (никаких новыз настроек там не стоит).

Да там плюс - я же говорю, бот ранее полгода назад работал...

На компе точно установлены последние версии, т.к. я на него ставил всё новой, а сам код загружен на него через Git

Я грешил больше на то, что что-то поменялось в библиотеке, но ничего нового и противоречащего тому, что уже написано, не нашел.

Тут еще прикольнее. Я ж говорил, что не работает бот ни с компа, ни с сервера. Но на сервере сообщество Дискорд и канал другие - и он тоже не работает. И он тоже ранее работал

Я не знаю как такое возможно. Первые 4 пункта самые распространенные, особенно последний - 4.
Могу точно сказать, что это не из-за изменений в библиотеке. Возможно, Вы просто действительно где-то недосмотрели.

Не понял, что вы имели ввиду "Но на сервере сообщество Дискорд и канал другие - и он тоже не работает."..

Программа есть также на специализированном сервере для запуска приложений на языке Python. Она раньше там работала, при этом у нее был прописан и другой токен (то есть это другой бот), и работал он с другим сообществом дискорд (соответственно и ID сообщества, и ID канала там другие). И он тоже перестал работать. Это я написал к тому, что это скорее всего не косяк конкретного сообщества Дискорд и его каналов, где кто-то что-то ограничил. Ошибка именно какая-то программная.

По части недосмотра - я вообще ничего не делал с программой. Она раньше работала, теперь не запускается....

А может проблема быть в нестабильном интернет-соединении?

Нет, причем здесь интернет-соединение? У вас ведь проблема после перезапуска бота, а не до него.

Бибилиотека Дискорд очень требовательна к интернету, бывало, что на начальных этапах это приводило к валетам из приложения


Убедитесь, что ваш бот имеет все необходимые разрешения для доступа к каналам.
Проверьте настройки разрешений в Discord Developer Portal и в сервере, где бот должен работать.
Если права были изменены, удалите бота с сервера и добавьте его снова, предоставив необходимые разрешения.
Если вы используете версию библиотеки discord.py 2.0 и выше, убедитесь, что параметры функций указаны правильно, так как в версии 2.0 были внесены изменения в порядок аргументов.
Регулярно проверяйте обновления документации discord.py, чтобы быть в курсе последних изменений.


как написать хороший ответ => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Да там действительно поменяли права моему боту, поэтому Дискорд его не воспринимал. После спила и перезалива бота с новыми правами всё заработало

Stack Overflow на русском — это сайт вопросов и ответов для профессиональных разработчиков программного обеспечения, энтузиастов программирования и системных администраторов. Сайт создан и управляется сообществом. С вами вместе мы создаём свободную библиотеку подробных ответов на любой прикладной вопрос по программированию и системному администрированию. приглашаем вас пройти тур => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour
ваш ответ был изменен (чтоб показать, как можно упорядочить написание), я взяла информацию из вашего ответа. Так он выглядит более структурирован и отмечен деталями на мой взгляд

Попробуйте обновить библиотеку discord
pip install --upgrade discord

Если это не поможет, то попробуйте метод await client.fetch_channel()
В своём начале с discord.py тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой, но сейчас мне данные функции не требуются. Если что вдруг проявится, комментируйте, постараюсь не забыть свою обязанность ответить на поставленные вопросы.

Там по правам бота на самом портале разработчиков Discord проблемы были. После того, как я удалили бота с канала и перелогинил его с правами, всё заработало

ок, буду иметь ввиду
